# Moen single handle shower control with push in diverter

Tags: spout, diverter

I have a Moen single handle shower control with push in diverter.

I replaced  the cartridge less than 2 yrs ago.

Sometimes I have   to  pull the diverter out by hand due to it sticking.

All of a sudden the water continues to run out of the spout when the handle is turned off.

Do I need to remove diverter also.

Comment: Sharon, We need more info if you want an informed answer. Model number of valve, type of diverter, I.E. how does the diverter work? (not sure what push in means exactly)  Photos may help.

Comment: Forget the diverter for a minute, are you saying that the water will not stop flowing when you shut off the control valve?